# How to pass yii2 search params through javascript api call

Tags: javascript, php, search, yii2

my search params is

```
$params=Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
```

And my api call is like

```
function doInBackground(){
      var params=<?=json_encode($params)?>;
       $.get('car/get-map-data',
          {
           "params":params
      },
      function(data){
        if(data)
        {
          console.log(data);
        }
      }); 
    }
```

But i am getting an error like

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Array to string conversion
```

on the line

```
var params=<?=json_encode($params)?>;
```

How to solve this.I want to pass the search params to another api.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getQueryString()`

```
function doInBackground(){
  var params=<?=Yii::$app->request->getQueryString();?>;
   $.get('car/get-map-data',
      {
       "params":params
  },
  function(data){
    if(data)
    {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: i tried this one.but the filter is not working from the server side.Do we need to convert this querystring to queryparams from the server side??

Answer (score 0):

I think that handling the query params via [**URLSearchParams**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) would be more **non-hacky** and clearer solution than obtaining them via PHP.

By *URLSearchParams* you can collect them into JS object and properly pass it as POST data to your AJAX request.